# how to implement two-way clustering in R

Tags: r, two-way

How to implement two-way clustering in R as in program PaST? I mean, crossing two dendrograms, one specimen dependent and the other variable dependent, and the matrix presented between the two. Like this.

Two way cluster in PaST, method="bray"
[image: two way cluster in PaST, method="bray"]

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the function mixOmics::cim() and to the package biclust?

Comment: Yes. But it results in a heatmap. I would like to get my data matrix in it, intsead.

Comment: have a look to the function heatmap.2 (package gplots) argument 'cellnote'.